# IOS 7 navigation bar with section Header BUG (space between navbar and Header Section)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationbar, sectionheader

In my iOS project i want to connect UITableView with Header Section and UINavigation Bar hidden on scrolling - and i have a bug: on a scrolling appear spacing between Navigation Bar and UITableView. But if i don't use Section Header all works good

[image]

For Header Section i use **[Apple example code](https://github.com/voke/iOS-Dev-Center-Sample-Code)**

For UINavigation Bar hidden on scrolling  i used many controls but  all have this problem

```
AMScrollingNavbar<br />
GTScrollNavigationBar<br />
NJKScrollFullScreen<br />

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Not solved problem

How to use together UITableViewControler with Header Section  and  UINavigation Bar hidden and haven't problem this spacing

Comment: add self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; to your viewCOntroller

Comment: Can I have your code for header?

Comment: "add self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;" - not solved problem

Comment: "Can I have your code for header?" - https://github.com/voke/iOS-Dev-Center-Sample-Code - here code for header, i don't changed him